# Как сделать анимирование при нажатии на кнопку?

Tags: css

Помогите пожалуйста с css анимированием как сделать так что бы анимирование воспроизводилось при нажатии на кнопку

```css
.cssload-container {
   text-align: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  
}

.cssload-speeding-wheel {
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 10px double;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
  
}

.cssload-speeding-wheel:before,
.cssload-speeding-wheel:after{
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 6px;
  height: 150%; 
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  z-index:1;
  left: calc(50% - 3px);
  top: -25%;
  animation: cssload-spin 675ms infinite linear;
        -o-animation: cssload-spin 675ms infinite linear;
        -ms-animation: cssload-spin 675ms infinite linear;
        -webkit-animation: cssload-spin 675ms infinite linear;
        -moz-animation: cssload-spin 675ms infinite linear;
}

@keyframes cssload-spin {
    100%{ transform: rotate(360deg); transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@-o-keyframes cssload-spin {
    100%{ -o-transform: rotate(360deg); transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@-ms-keyframes cssload-spin {
    100%{ -ms-transform: rotate(360deg); transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes cssload-spin {
    100%{ -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@-moz-keyframes cssload-spin {
    100%{ -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
.cssload-speeding-wheel:after {
 transform: rotate(90deg)
}
```

```html
<div class="cssload-container">
<div class="cssload-speeding-wheel"></div>
</div>
<button>Click</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Без javascript не получится.
Вот пример https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_style_animation

Comment: можно. с помощью input[type="checkbox"]. Надо смотреть на состояние `:checked` у checkbox

Comment: Анимация запуститься только один раз. Повторно не запустится. Ну или у меня так и не получилось это реализовать.

Comment: Скоро напишу ответ, покажу

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать анимацию, но не очень удобно.
Тут я использовал `@property` и изменение `CSS-variables` в `@keyframes`, это пока что работает только в `Chromium` браузерах. Но вы можете сделать такую же простую анимацию без `CSS-variables`

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

:root {
  --transitionTimingFunction: ease;
  --transitionDuration: 0.2s;
}

@property --percent {
  syntax: '<integer>';
  inherits: false;
  initial-value: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.input-group {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  gap: 10px;
}

.checkbox {
  display: none;
}

.checkbox-label {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition-timing-function: var(--transitionTimingFunction);
  transition-duration: var(--transitionDuration);
  transition-property: color, background-color, border-color;
}

.circle-svg {
  display: block;
  max-width: 50px;
  --PI: 3.141592;
  --r: 30;
  --PiR2: calc( var(--PI) * var(--r) * 2);
}

.circle-svg circle {
  r: var(--r);
}

.circle-svg__thumb {
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: transparent;
}

.circle-svg__track {
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform-box: fill-box;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  --percent: 0;
  stroke-dasharray: calc(var(--PiR2) * var(--percent) / 100) var(--PiR2);
}

.checkbox:checked+.checkbox-label {
  background-color: black;
  border-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.checkbox:checked+.checkbox-label+.circle-svg .circle-svg__track {
  animation: circleAnimate 2s infinite alternate linear;
}

@keyframes circleAnimate {
  0% {
    --percent: 0;
  }
  100% {
    --percent: 100;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="input-group">

  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="checkbox-1" hidden>
  <label for="checkbox-1" class="checkbox-label">
   <span>Кнопка</span>
  </label>

  <svg class="circle-svg" viewbox="0 0 64 64">
    <circle class="circle-svg__thumb" cx="50%" cy="50%">           </circle>
    <circle class="circle-svg__track" cx="50%" cy="50%">           </circle>
  </svg>

</div>
```